# Componentes duplicados en Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un proyecto en angular4 y al avanzar van las rutas muy bien pero llega un componente donde lo pone en la parte superior de otro, y cuando le doy "atras" me va mostrando todas las pantallas de los componentes repetidas hacia abajo o arriba, dejo una imagen de como lo hace. y el codigo de mi routes.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    component: WelcomeComponent,
},

{ path: "about", component: AboutComponent },
{ path: "tips", component: TipsComponent },

{ path: "q1", component: Q1Component },

{ path: "fin", component: FinComponent },

{
    path: "**",
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}];
```

[image: Lo de arriba de la línea azul es un componente y lo de abajo es otro pero se ven lo dos en la misma ruta]

En algunas ocasiones mando llamar el componente asi desde un botón:

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/about' ]" routerLinkActive="active">
```

Comenzar

y en otras con una función:

```
<button class="btn btn-simple" (click)="startQuiz()">¡Estoy listo!</button>

startQuiz(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('q1');   
 }
```

Comment: Parece problema de `router-outlet` duplicado. En que componente lo tienes?

Comment: Lo tengo en mi app.component.html  y mi app-root esta en el index principal.

Comment: Alguno de estos componentes lo colocas de forma directa en lugar de viajar hacia el de forma manual?

Comment: Deje la forma en que llamo los componentes para navegación. Gracias por la ayuda